# Apply style to selected text not selected box

Tags: vba, powerpoint

this is going to be easy for any VBA expert out there so, apologies for the novice question! I have a code to condense text into a text box. At the moment the code condensed all the text inside the text box but I want the code to work for selected text only. How can I modify this code to make it work?

Many thanks on advance!
PJ

Sub CondenseText()

```
On Error GoTo Catch


Dim o As Shape, b As Boolean
Set o = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
If Not o Is Nothing Then
    With o
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing - 0.1
    End With
End If
Exit Sub
```

Catch:
    If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then MsgBox CG_NOTHING_SELECTED
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CondenseText()

Dim oTextRange2 As TextRange2

' You can check Selection.Type rather than relying
' on an errorhandler if you like
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionText Then

    Set oTextRange2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2

    If Not oTextRange2 Is Nothing Then
        oTextRange2.Font.Spacing = oTextRange2.Font.Spacing - 0.1
    End If

' and you could add an Else clause with msg for the 
' user here if you like:
Else
    MsgBox "Yo! Select some text first, OK?"    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What else can I say other than Genius?!! Thanks a lot!